# PostgreSQL visibility of records changes from other transaction inside the current one

Tags: postgresql, transaction, concurrency, serialization

I have a table "tst" which has a "status" column using which we process records in that table.
Once the records are processed we set the status to 'Y';

```
    #\d tst
                 Table "core.tst"
     Column |  Type   | Modifiers
    --------+---------+-----------
     id     | integer | not null
     status | text    |
    Indexes:
            "amn2_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Issue: At the start of the long(approx 20 mins) transaction I have 3 records in tst table as shown below

```
    #select * from tst;
     id | status
    ----+--------
        1 | N
        2 | N
        3 | N
    (3 rows)
```

But during the transaction I have couple of more records being inserted into the tst table, but I was assuming that these new records will not be visible to the current transaction, but proved wrong on testing.

Session 1:

```
    DO $$ 
    BEGIN 
        perform pg_sleep(20) ; 
        UPDATE amn2 SET des = 'Y' ; 
    END $$;
```

Session 2:

```
    INSERT INTO tst VALUES ( 4, 'N');
```

Post the Session 1, all the records were updated to status 'Y' including id 4.

Is this expected? Or some DB/table serializable set up missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was assuming that these new records will not be visible to the current transaction, but proved wrong on testing.

That's not the case in the default `READ COMMITTED` isolation. Changes from *committed* transactions become visible at the start of the next statement in a transaction. Each statement still has a snapshot, so you can't have rows appear *within* a statement.

You can use `SERIALIZABLE` isolation to get that behaviour, but it has a performance impact and can lead to table bloat on fast-changing tables.

See [the documentation on transaction isolation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html) to understand what is going on.